# Log viewer for SOAP traces with xml pretty print

Tags: logging, soap

My application produce traces will sent and received soap messages. I'm looking for freeware log viewr which is able to pretty print soap message.

Comment: SoapUi is testing app, I need tool for investigating application traces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm developing[OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). It detects soap message in log message and formats it. Additionally it also do some coloring.
Take a look at screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfVfb.png
OtrosLogViewer is on apache license.